# strip arbitrary number of matches from start of string in zsh parameter expansion

Tags: zsh

With parameter expansion I can remove a leading white space e.g. with

```
stripped_var=${original_var#[[:blank:]]}
```

I'm familiar that `##` instead of `#` allows matching the largest match instead of the smallest match, but haven't found how to convert the pattern from "one white space" to "an arbitrary number of white spaces".

Is there a way to allow multiple matches to strip of all leading white spaces from the value of `original_var`? Ideally I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve launching a subprocess/subshell (i.e. I'd prefer a solution without awk, sed, … though if parameter expansion can't do that I might as well resort to these)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [extended glob operator](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Operators) `x#`:

> x#
> (Requires EXTENDED_GLOB to be set.) Matches zero or more occurrences of the pattern x. This operator has high precedence; ‘12#’ is equivalent to ‘1(2#)’, rather than ‘(12)#’. It is an error for an unquoted ‘#’ to follow something which cannot be repeated; this includes an empty string, a pattern already followed by ‘##’, or parentheses when part of a KSH_GLOB pattern (for example, ‘!(foo)#’ is invalid and must be replaced by ‘*(!(foo))’).

```
setopt extended_glob
stripped_var=${original_var##[[:blank:]]#}
```

Answer (score 1):

As [@Freddy mentioned](/a/633597), with `zsh` you can use the `[[:blank:]]#` pattern as the equivalent of regexp's `[[:blank:]]*` or `ksh`'s `*([[:blank:]])`.

But POSIXly, you can also do:

```
stripped_var=${orginal_var#"${original_var%%[![:blank:]]*}"}
```

For the equivalent of `awk '{$1=$1};1'`, that is strip leading and trailing blanks and squeeze sequences of blanks into one space, you can do:

```
var=$'  a    b\tc\t\td\t \n\n'
stripped_var=${${=var}}
```

(here `$stripped_var` becomes `"a b c d"`). That is do `$IFS`-splitting and cast to scalar again which joins the elements with the first character of `$IFS`.